# Convert a cell containing matrices to a 2d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I want to find easy way to convert a 1x324 cell array which contains matrices to a 2-dimensional matrix.

Each of the cell array's elements is a matrix of size 27x94, so they contain 2538 different values. I want to convert this cell array of matrices to a 324x2538 matrix - where the rows of the output contain each matrix (as a row vector) from the cell array.

---

To clarify what my data looks like and what I'm trying to create, see this example:

```
matrix1 = [1,2,3,4,...,94 ; 95,96,97,... ; 2445,2446,2447,...,2538]; % (27x94 matrix)
% ... other matrices are similar
A = {matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, ..., matrix324}; % Matrices are in 1st row of cell array
```

What I am trying to get:

```
% 324x2538 output matrix
B = [1     , 2   ,   ..., 2538  ;  % matrix1
     2539  , 2540,   ..., 5076  ;  % matrix2
     ...   
     819775, 819776, ..., 822312];
```

Comment: Please learn your [data types](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types_data-types.html), the original wording in this question made it very confusing! You can't have a matrix which contains cells, since matrices can only contain numerical data. I have edited your question to make it clearer for future visitors, since you haven't replied with a clarification, but in future try not to be ambiguous in the first place, it encourages better answers.

Answer (score 3):

The [`cell2mat`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) function does exactly that. The doc example:

```
C = {[1],    [2 3 4];
     [5; 9], [6 7 8; 10 11 12]};
A = cell2mat(C)
A = 

     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12
```

You have your matrix now, so just rework it to contain rows:

```
B = rand(27,302456); % your B
D = reshape(B,27,94,324); % stack your matrices to 3D
E = reshape(D,1, 2538,324); % reshape each slice to a row vector
E = permute(E,[3 2 1]); % permute the dimensions to the correct order
% Based on sizes instead of fixed numbers
% D = reshape(B, [size(A{1}) numel(A)]);
% E = reshape(D,[1 prod(size(A{1})) numel(A)]);
% E = permute(E,[3 2 1]); % permute the dimensions to the correct order
```

Or, to one line it from your `B`:

```
B = reshape(B,prod(size(A{1})),numel(A)).'
```

Comment: I tried that but it creates 27x30456 matrix and what I need is should create 324x2538 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the solution and I will add it here if anyone have similar problems in future:

```
for ii = 1:length(A)
    B{ii} = A{ii}(:);
end
B = cell2mat(B).';
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to write this would be using `cellfun` to operate on each element of the cell, then concatenating the result.

```
% Using your input cell array A, turn all matrices into column vectors
% You need shiftdim so that the result is e.g. [1 2 3 4] not [1 3 2 4] for [1 2; 3 4]
B = cellfun(@(r) reshape(shiftdim(r,1),[],1), A, 'uniformoutput', false);
% Stack all columns vectors together then transpose
B = [B{:}].';
```